# How to write update query using 2 tables and conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update/revise the department names in a table called `"DEPART_NAMES_AS_SUBMITTED"` using another table called `"DEPART_NAMES_REQUIRED."` I would like this update to occur only if the line numbers in `"DEPART_NAMES_AS_SUBMITTED"` are within the line number range  [LOW] [HIGH] in the second table called `"DEPART_NAMES_REQUIRED."` If the line number is less/more than the [LOW] [HIGH] range the department name should remain the same. I have unsuccessfully tried numerous SQLs including the following:

```
 UPDATE DEPT_NAMES_SUBMITTED INNER JOIN DEPT_NAMES_REQUIRED ON(DEPT_NAMES_SUBMITTED.LINE_NUMBER = DEPT_NAMES_REQUIRED.HIGH) AND (DEPT_NAMES_SUBMITTED.LINE_NUMBER = DEPT_NAMES_REQUIRED.LOW) SET DEPT_NAMES_SUBMITTED.DEPART_NAME = [DEPT_NAMES_REQUIRED].[DEPART_NAME]
 WHERE (((DEPT_NAMES_REQUIRED.LINE_NUMBER) Between [low] And [high]));
```

Thank you for taking the time to read and answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is fine if you remove the square braces and put in the right logic:

```
UPDATE DEPT_NAMES_SUBMITTED ns INNER JOIN
       DEPT_NAMES_REQUIRED hr
       ON ns.LINE_NUMBER <= nr.HIGH AND 
          ns.LINE_NUMBER >= nr.LOW
    SET ns.DEPART_NAME = nr.DEPART_NAME;
```

Notice that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.